# "empower with" or "empower by" or something else

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, motto

I'am thinking a motto of a technology startup. I'm wondering which one is better:

```
NAME empowers smartphone users with leading machine learning technologies and solutions.
```

or

```
NAME empowers smartphone users by leading machine learning technologies and solutions.
```

or

```
NAME powers up smartphone users with leading machine learning technologies and solutions.
```

or

```
NAME brings leading machine learning technologies and solutions to smartphone users.
```

I prefer `empower` than `provide` and `allow`, because it feels like `giving power to someone`, am I correct?

Does anyone have a good idea for the motto?

Comment: I am voting to close, because this could be the new poster question for opinion based questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this but okay...

Going based off your examples I'd use *with* becuase *by* sounds wrong (at least to my ear, it doesn't sound right) and doesn't create a connection with your product. *With* sounds symbiotic while *by* sounds causal.

*Empowers* is a better verb becuase it also creates a better relationship than just *powers*.

After your edit, *brings* could work if you are a provider in something like a service rather than a product, but again this creates something that seems like a causal relationship than a symbiotic one which can make people feel better.